# Laravel + Swift Mailer: Error: no valid recipients

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, swiftmailer

Note: this sadly is no [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616706/how-do-we-solve-error-554-5-5-1-no-valid-recipients-when-using-php-swiftmailer?rq=1), I already tried everything mentioned there.

I tried to set up a connection to my mailserver with `Laravel/Swiftmailer`. The Mailing section of my .env looks as follows:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=<THE MAILHOST>
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=<THE USERNAME>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<THE PASSWORD>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Personal information is censored for obvious reasons, but the configuration does work. I tested it by connecting to the server with this configuration with thunderbird and it works like a charm.

Here is where I call the Mailable:

```
   public function from_id(string $id): User
   {
         .
         .
         .
        Mail::to(<WORKING EMAIL ADRESS>)->send(new OrderShipped());
    }
```

Thats how the Mailable looks like (it basically is the example one from the laravel docs):

```
   public function build()
   {
      return $this->view('email_templates.simple_test');
   }
```

I debugged into the code and there are actually two exceptions thrown, altough whoops! only shows the latter:

> Expected response code 250/251/252 but got code "554", with message
>   "554 5.7.1 : Recipient address rejected: Access
>   denied"
>
> Expected response code 354 but got code "554", with message "554 5.5.1
>   Error: no valid recipients"

I tried to sent an email from the perfectly working mailserver via thunderbird to the `<WORKING EMAIL ADRESS>` and the mail got sent and received in a fraction of a second and without any problems/errors. Basically, I tried to reproduce the exact same scenario with a different tool. So from my point of view, the error must be in the codebase.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can it be that the SMTP mail server service is refusing your recipient email address?

Comment: @TomTom No, because, as I stated, it works perfectly if I send an email to same adress (<WORKING EMAIL ADRESS>) from the same server using thunderbird.

Comment: can you var_dump(<working email>) just before Mail::to(<WORKING EMAIL ADRESS>)->send(new OrderShipped()); show us the result ?

Comment: @AabirHussain It's a raw string containing personal information. So no, sorry. But it definetely does work, as I described in the last paragraph.

Comment: What is the email service provider (gmail or zoho or ...). Has the MX record configured been configured (if email is under your domain)? And as @AabirHussain said, just trim the personal information and let us know the var_dump result

Comment: @HášílPáůďýál The email service provider is the hoster of my website. Yes, the MXRR has been configured. As I pointed out int the last paragraph, it works fine from a different client. The var_dump result of the raw string I put there for test is: "string(22) <PERSONAL INFORMATION>@mapawa.eu". I actually copy & pasted the string into thunderbird and sent an sucessfully send an email to this adress from the very adress that is also set in my laravel app.

Comment: What's in the mail server logs?

Comment: @Lou I can't access them directly unfortunately, but I sent a ticket to my hosting provider so they send them to me to evaluate them.

Comment: Sound to me like you're site is hitting the spam prevention of the recipients email server. You might need to implement DKIM / SPF to stop this from happening.

Comment: @Jamesking56 The recipient adress is hosted on the same server. Also, as I pointed out in the question, it does work from a diffrerent client.

Comment: Are you using goDaddy server for hosting ?

Comment: @AabirHussain No, I use [manitu](https://www.manitu.de).

Comment: I assume you're using gmail smtp settings, right ?
Because i'm facing same issue

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI No, I don't. Please read the comments above.

Comment: The thing is that this error is very generic. Especially if you only have the verbose from PHP. In the mail server logs you would probably have about 20 lines of verbose for every email that you failed to send. It would be MUCH easier to pinpoint where the problem is coming from exactly. The problem could be anywhere from auth to antispam to blacklists, some people have seen this error due to DNS issues, name it. I really hope you can get a hand on those logs from your hosting provider. Meanwhile you could try to install the swiftmailer logger plugin. Maybe add the dump to your thread.

Comment: @Lou I'd like to give the Swifmail Logger a try. Can you help me out with a link, perhaps.

Comment: @mapawa Can you try by changing `from address` to some real email id in `config/mail.php`?

Comment: I have the same isssue and for me it seems it's caused by accented characters in the sender's name

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a SMTP error, what kind of error code you are getting ?

**Code 354**: means the SMTP server telling Laravel to proceed and send the body of the email. Note that this is what is expected, and not what you received.

**Code 554**: from a SMTP server indicates: "Transaction Failed", and you'll note that this is what you actually got.

The reason this is failing is indicated further in the message: "Error: no valid recipients."

Without further data it will be hard to tell why the recipient isn't set properly on your codebase.

For complete list of smtp erro codes can visit: https://sendgrid.com/blog/smtp-server-response-codes-explained/

Comment: Please reread the quote from the question. `Expected response code 354 but got code "554"`. So Laravel **expected**  code 354, but **got** code 554. There is a valid reciepient adress set in the codebase, as mentioned in the question and comments.

Comment: You need the actual log message from the SMTP server. In my case, I haven't configured SMTP authentication when sending automatic notifications from the app. The SMTP server responded with "Relay access denied". I configured SMTP authentication and now the app can send mail to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact your sysadmin to ask if you need STARTTLS or just TLS.

STARTTLS starts a plain connection and then switches to a secure TLS 'channel', TLS connects to secure connection directly but is less compatible.

if the answer is STARTTLS use the port 587
else keep your port but verify it with your sysadmin

another reason could be that you account was banned or your IP blocked

Comment: You seem to be the first one that actually read the question. I am in contact with the customer support at the moment, we will see if your recommendation is correct.

Comment: I had the same or a very similar issue with exactly the same Laravel project. My test installation was connected to my SMTP server and the production installation to the SMTP server of a customer (Office365). For some email addresses, my mail server has rejected sending the mail but Office365 hasn't. It was a strange behavior, I solved it by switching to STARTTLS.

Comment: @Johannes Unfortunately, the same error occurs when switching to tls.

Comment: then maybe your account was banned or you mail blacklisted or your ip blocked by the server

Comment: `another reason could be that you account was banned or your IP blocked` – Funny for me it was after I debugged something different I tried to send test emails to `test@example.com`. Those led to the error OP had. After I switched sending to **a real email address** everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

My answer isn't Laravel specific, as I'm working in Yii2 environment, but the error message was the same as above. (Maybe I'll help someone someday.)

My original problem: the contact form was not working while at other places the app was sending out automatic mails properly - which was weird.

It turned out that when setting the 'from address' in the SwiftMailer config I put in the contacting person's (sender's) e-mail address, which was not allowed.

When I configured the proper user account (which I use to authenticate to the SMTP server) as the sender address, there was no issue. As soon as I tried to 'mimic' that the users are sending the e-mails from their own addresses, I was given that same message.

All I could do to "fix" this is to include the 'ReplyTo' parameter with the e-mail, this way when I reply to the incoming mail in Outlook, the actual sender's address is populated instead of the SMTP mailbox used for contact-mail-sending.

I've also included a short message at the bottom of the Body to indicate who the sender is (name and address) - just for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks a little strange to me. Please try with the below syntax (note here I've included a `$_orderObject` variable as a placeholder to represent order details):

app/Mail/OrderShipped.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;

class OrderShipped extends Mailable
{
    protected $_name;
    protected $_orderObject;

    public function __construct($name, $order)
    {
        $this->_name = $name;
        $this->_orderObject = $order
    }

    public function build ()
    {
        return $this->to (<CONFIRMED WORKING EMAIL>)
                    ->subject ('New Order!')
                    ->view ('email_templates.simple_test')
                    ->with ([
                       'name' => $this->_name,
                       'order' => $this->_orderObject
                    ]);
    }
}
```

//calling it

```
   public function from_id(string $id): User
   {
        $name = << $this->getUserNameById ($id) >> // fake method
        $orderObject = << $this->getLatestOrderByUserId($id) >> // fake method

        Mail::send(new OrderShipped($name, $orderObject));
    }
```